# VSTO Outlook Add-In published ClickOnce slow load time

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, add-in

I created VSTO Outlook add-in that has a button within the main ribbon of outlook and when clicked it lunches windows form. It works great to send the data from the form to the database and it composes email as well.
My problem is that users within a company that had it installed are getting slow load notification and the add-in is disabled. I tried to fix it and change all code for multi-threading but it seems not to improve the load time much. Is there any other way to make sure add-in on all user's machines is always enabled. Maybe some other way to publish other than ClickOnce.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multithreading won't help you much - Outlook looks at your addin startup times, not the time it takes to respond to the button click.

If you are using .Net, you get punished for that - the .Net run-time has to be loaded before a single line of your addin code gets executed. Unless you switch to an unmanaged language (such as C++ or Delphi), there is nothing you can do about that.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Dmitry Streblechenko , I will have a look at how could I change from .net to C++ to improve loading time

Comment: Would you have some guide on how to create unmanaged addin that enables my .net VSTO addin? Thanks in advance. I would created C++ addin that only enables my .net addin if it is disabled.

Comment: Addins cannot be programmatically re-enabled - you can do that either through the Outlook UI or by editing a few registry keys.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I would have to TeamViewer all people that have add-in disabled.